# IF-ELSE SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, if-statement

I'm having a problem executing this SQL statement. I am new to TSQL and I have no idea how to fix this. Everytime I execute this, I get the error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
> condition is expected, near ')'.
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.

```
if
SELECT Num from users where SUBSTRING(CAST(Num AS VARCHAR(6)),1,2) = 14
     print 'Batch 2014';
else
     print 'Batch 2013';
```

What I'm trying to do here is to search in my table all users with '13' as the first 2 numbers in the column 'Num', and then print 'Batch 2014' else 'Batch 2013' Please help :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to avoid using `if-else` with exists. Why?

1. You need to make sure at least one record exists in your table
2. The other benefit of EXISTS is that once it finds a single record that matches it stops processing. This doesn't have a huge impact if you're checking on a primary key. It does have a big impact if you're checking for existence based on another field

   ```
   if exists (SELECT Num from users where SUBSTRING(CAST(Num AS VARCHAR(6)), 1, 2) = 14)
        print 'Batch 2014';
   else
        print 'Batch 2013';`
   ```

Comment: thank you! it works but, I need to select only those users with a '14' as the first two numbers in the column 'Num'. How will I do that?

Comment: test comparator like `where num like '14%'`

Comment: thank you again!! May I know what's the purpose of the '%' sign? :)

Comment: `%` Any string of zero or more characters. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms179859.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  Num
            FROM    users
            WHERE   SUBSTRING(CAST(Num AS VARCHAR(6)), 1, 2) = 14 ) 
    PRINT 'Batch 2014' ;
ELSE 
    PRINT 'Batch 2013' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

What the type of Num?

syntax of `IF-ELSE`:

```
-- Syntax for SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Data Warehouse, Parallel Data Warehouse  

IF Boolean_expression   
     { sql_statement | statement_block }   
[ ELSE   
     { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
```

So, "`SELECT Num from users where SUBSTRING(CAST(Num AS VARCHAR(6)),1,2) = 14`" should return a Boolean, `True` or `False`.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT Num from users where SUBSTRING(CAST(Num AS VARCHAR(6)),1,2) = 14)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition returns non-boolean value (other that `0` or `1`),that's the reason for getting the error.

If you are using `if .. exists` it will print if any of the num in your table satisfies the condition `SUBSTRING(CAST(Num AS VARCHAR(6)),1,2) = 14`.

If you wanted to see the users with batch information ,use CASE statement.

```
SELECT userid,Name -- mention the columns you wanted to select
      ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(CAST(Num AS VARCHAR(6)),1,2) =14 THEN 'Batch 2014' 
        ELSE 'Batch 2013' END Batch 
FROM users
```

Comment: Will `if` return a non-boolean value?